# how to make an if else statement for character length

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a piece of code that will see if the text entry has 50 or more characters and if it does then to just show the 50 plus ellipsis (...)  or else if it has less than 50 characters then to just show the whole entry without the ellipsis.

My current code is:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about"""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model"""
        return self.text

class Entry(models.Model):
    """Something specific learned about a topic"""
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

    def __str__(self):
        if text.len() >= 50:
            """Return a string represerntation of the model"""
            return self.text[:50] + "..."
        else:
            return self.text
```

When I run this while using Python and Django I keep getting an error. How would i go about fixing this

Comment: What is the error are you're getting?

Comment: Your last function needs to be indented, presumably...

Comment: Also in your last function, you need `len(self.text)`, not `text.len()`.

Comment: currently gettings self 
Error in formatting: NameError: name 'text' is not defined

Comment: See my second comment above...

Comment: `if text.len() >= 50:` -> `if self.text.len() >= 50:`

Comment: @allcaps: Does a Django TextField have a len  member function? (genuine question)

Comment: In Python len() returns the length (the number of items) of an object. The argument may be a sequence (such as a string, bytes, tuple, list, or range) or a collection (such as a dictionary, set, or frozen set). https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about"""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model"""
        return self.text

class Entry(models.Model):
    """Something specific learned about a topic"""
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

    def __str__(self):
        if len(self.text) >= 50:
            """Return a string represerntation of the model"""
            return self.text[:50] + "..."
        else:
            return self.text
```

Comment: Code only answers are not ideal. Please review [answer] and tell us *why it didn't work* and *how this fixes it*.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
if len(self.text) >= 50:
```

instead of:

```
if text.len() >= 50:
```